# Inconsistency using list() function on a CSV reader

Tags: python, python-2.7

While researching options for an oft-asked question (How to find the number of rows in a CSV reader before iterating), I came across the approach of using `len(list(myCSVReader))`.  Yes, I know how klunky and potentially expensive this is, and I won't be using it.  But while playing with it, I came across a really puzzling inconsistency:

```
#myFile.txt is a 3-line CSV file
myCSV = csv.reader(open('myFile.txt','rb'),dialect='excel')
print(len(list(myCSV)))
print(list(myCSV))
```

When I run this, I get:

```
> 3
> []
```

I can understand why you couldn't just use `list()` to convert the reader to a list of lists, but if that's the case, then how/why does a `len()` on this produce the correct result?

-- JDM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what happens when you build a `list` from a `generator`.

- Generator is an iterable object that yields items one by one. At some point it is exhausted.
- `csv.reader` returns a generator.
- When you do `list(generator)`, the list constructor consumes all items from the generator.
- Next time you try getting something from the generator (e.g. do `list(generator)` another time), it's already exhausted.

**What you can do** is
create a list once and use it where needed:

```
myCSV = list(csv.reader(open('myFile.txt','rb'),dialect='excel'))
print(len(myCSV))
print(myCSV)
```

Comment: OK, I get it now.  So if I reverse the `print` lines, I get the list of lists, and then a 0.

Comment: @user1905392 Right. You only get the items once.